# Combine multiple getEntityRecords calls

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, javascript, block-editor

I have a block that references a custom post type named **faq** that has a taxonomy named **faq_group**. This block has one attribute and makes multiple `getEntityRecords` calls. One of the calls has an argument that depends on the previous one:

The attribute:

```
// the group attribute stores the slug of the selected faq_group slug from a SelectControl component
attributes: {
    group: {
        type: 'string',
        default: '',
    },
}
```

The calls:

```
// Get all terms from the faq_group taxonomy to fill a SelectControl component (name and slug)
const groups = useSelect( ( select ) =>
    select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'taxonomy', 'faq_group', { per_page: -1, orderby: 'name', order: 'asc', _fields: 'id,name,slug' } ),
    []
);

// Get the term object with the same slug as the group attribute
const selectedGroup = useSelect( ( select ) =>
    select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'taxonomy', 'faq_group', { per_page: -1, orderby: 'name', order: 'asc', _fields: 'id,name,slug' } )?.find( ( term ) => term.slug === attributes.group ),
    [ attributes.group ]
);

// Get posts from the faq custom post type with a faq_group term with id = selectedGroup.id
const faqs = useSelect( ( select ) =>
    select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'postType', 'faq', { faq_group: [ selectedGroup?.id ] } ),
    [ selectedGroup?.id ]
);
```

My question is, can this be simplified somehow? Can the multiple calls be combined inside just one `useSelect` selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can the multiple calls be combined inside just one `useSelect`
> selector?

Yes, and here's an example where my `useSelect()` returns an object that I unpack using the destructuring assignment (e.g. `const { a, b } = myFunc()` where `myFunc()` returns `{ a: 'foo', b: 123 }`):

```js
const { groups, selectedGroup, faqs } = useSelect( ( select ) => {
    const { getEntityRecords } = select( 'core' );

    // The args are identical for both "groups" and selectedGroup, so I put them in a constant.
    const groupsArgs = { per_page: -1, orderby: 'name', order: 'asc', _fields: 'id,name,slug' };

    const selectedGroup = getEntityRecords( 'taxonomy', 'faq_group', groupsArgs )?.find(
        ( term ) => term.slug === attributes.group
    );

    return {
        groups: getEntityRecords( 'taxonomy', 'faq_group', groupsArgs ),
        faqs: getEntityRecords( 'postType', 'faq', { faq_group: [ selectedGroup?.id ] } ),
        selectedGroup,
    };
}, [ attributes.group ] );
```

If you do not actually need to access the `selectedGroup` from *outside* the `useSelect()` callback, then you can omit `selectedGroup` from the list, i.e. use just `const { groups, faqs } = useSelect( ... )`, and then remove the `selectedGroup,` (the third line) from the return value.

And actually, instead of calling `getEntityRecords()` twice with the same args, you could call it just once:

```js
const { groups, selectedGroup, faqs } = useSelect( ( select ) => {
    const { getEntityRecords } = select( 'core' );

    const groupsArgs = { per_page: -1, orderby: 'name', order: 'asc', _fields: 'id,name,slug' };
    const groups = getEntityRecords( 'taxonomy', 'faq_group', groupsArgs );

    const selectedGroup = groups?.find( ( term ) => term.slug === attributes.group );

    return {
        groups,
        selectedGroup,
        faqs: getEntityRecords( 'postType', 'faq', { faq_group: [ selectedGroup?.id ] } ),
    };
}, [ attributes.group ] );
```